# Why can't I see the changes in my project but I see them in the fxml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a problem with my project in JavaFX. I use SceneBuilder which saves all changes to fxml file, but when i run project I see only empty background, even the size of the working area does not change. I try to clean project and workspace but problem is the same. I have refresh project and all files and nothing, I choose "Refresh using native hooks or pooling" but i have all time this same problem. Does anyone have any other idea? I use java 13 and JavaFX 11

mainWindow.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"  prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com   /fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainWindowController">
<children>
<Label fx:id="labelText" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="42.0"   prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="0.0" text="" />
<Button fx:id="button1" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="82.0"  mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
</children>
</Pane>
```

main.class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
             scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass()
                  .getResource("mainWindow.fxml").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainWindowController class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Label labelText;
    @FXML
    Button button1;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        labelText.setText("Start");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't know JavaFX well enough to help here, or even if this is a problem, but you do realize you're setting `max/min` values to _negative_ infinity, right? `<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"`

Comment: @Christopher Schneider it doesn't matter, I can clean the .fxml file or write the worst stupid things and the effect is the same. Does not change workspace.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider That's actually constant that has a special meaning: [`Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)

Comment: @programbeginer0235 Have you double checked the resource is actually updated in the classpath? `try(InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("mainWindow.fxml")); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) { String l; while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(l);}`?

Comment: @fabian yes i have checked he is in classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in your start method in main. Try this implementation instead.

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainWindow.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[This is what you expected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF4bY.png)